# 6-outlet wall mount with dual active plugs and widely spaced outlets

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I'm looking for a wall outlet adapter converting two outlets to six, like [this GE one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009HKEXM). However, for reasons I don't comprehend, that adapter (and all its clones) have only one active plug, the other being a [plastic dummy](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1Q6IAAWIK7JVV/). Adapters that plug into both outlets do exist ([example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073JTH817)) but the outlets they provide are too closely spaced for most wart transformers.

Are there hybrids between [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073JTH817) [two](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009HKEXM) wall outlet adapters?

Comment: If the outlets are too close together, then use the short "pigtail" extension cords for some of the receptacles.

Comment: Who cares?  One set of blades is good for 20A, so perfectly adequate for 12A continuous, which is all you should be putting on a 15A circuit (blades parallel). If they are *all* wall-warts, that just won't be a problem.  If you are getting heating, it's because your receptacle or adapter has a problem. It's rare for a receptacle to be a Cheese piece of junk, but *very common* for an 'adapter' to be.  GE is as good a brand as they get, I sure wouldn't put something called "Fosman" in an outlet.  UL listed, yeah right.

Comment: Advertising (or marking) a product as "ETL listed" would be fraud if it's not actually true. Anyone having one can look up the model number at Intertek, e.g, the one shown in OP's example (Fosmon).

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the one active plug is because the one you show is rated 15A which is what that configuration will carry so there is no reason to have two. On your other question you might look at the ones that have USB ports and outlets. The ports wouldn't require a transformer. last resort would be an old fashion ugly three way or cross adapter.

Good Luck

Comment: Good answer, and for clarification I'd like to add, for the OP, that the top and bottom of an outlet are not two circuits. They are the same circuit. It really does sound like you just need a power strip.

Comment: Except in the case of a MWBC.